# Own lib, another computer: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

Today my testing went on, but I always got : "cannot open shared object file". So I made a little programm including the most important things:

The bin: Test; The lib: TestLib

The lib:

h:

```
 class TestLib{
  public:
   TestLib();
   void DoSome();
 };
```

cpp:

```
 #include "testlib.h"
 #include <iostream>

 TestLib::TestLib(){
 }

 void TestLib::DoSome(){
  std::cout << "Hallo Test_Lib!" << std::endl; std::cout.flush();
 }
```

The bin:

QT creator pro.file:

```
    HOME = $$system(echo $HOME)
    TEMPLATE = app
    CONFIG += console
    CONFIG -= app_bundle
    CONFIG -= qt

    SOURCES += main.cpp

    LIBS += -L$$HOME/Test_Lib/Libs/ -Wl,-rpath=$$HOME/Test_Lib/Libs/ -lTestLib -ldl -lpthread -lrt

    INCLUDEPATH += $$HOME/Test_Lib/Includes/
    DEPENDPATH += $$HOME/Test_Lib/Includes/
```

and main():

```
    #include "testlib.h"

    int main(){
        TestLib nLib;
        nLib.DoSome();
        return 0;
    }
```

The files on each computer are in

```
   /home/USERNAME/Test_Lib
   /home/USERNAME/Test_Lib/Includes/
   /home/USERNAME/Test_Lib/Libs/
```

On the development computer I can run ./Test and the output is "Hallo Test_Lib!".

But on my other computer I get the error "cannot open shared object file: libTestLib : no such file or directory".

Both computers have Linux Mint-17-64-KDE installed...

How do I get it working?

Greeting Earlybite

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your Lib is a shared object. You have 2 solutions :

- You can use a static lib (.a file) so the shared object won't be needed at runtime (it will be directly embedded in your executable file)
- You can also provide the LibTestLib file with your binary file (Exactly like you would do for a DLL on Windows).

Comment: Make static linking sense? I do not know on which computer the programm is running...
You mean placing the lib into the same dir as the bin is?
Meanwhile I found something out:
Terminal -> export LB_LIBRARY_PATH = /Path/To/Lib
Terminal -> sudo ldconfig
Now ./Test on the other computer also gets the output "Hallo Test_Lib!".
But how can I use that solution inside the bin (./Test)?

Comment: Sorry for the nonsense..; Fixed it
For your Lib path, you can put your lib file in standard Lib location (/usr/local/lib if I remember well)

Comment: But I wanted to have my libs in an own folder, like the headers too. E.g.: /home/USERNAME/A_Prog/, /.../Libs/, /.../Includes/ a.s.o.
What I do not understand is, that my linking gets the HOME-dir and with this the path to libs. But the libs won't get found in that path! Why? And why else should I use -wl -rpath?